# Dataframe : using all the values of an other column for a regression and then storing the result at the same index as the corresponding value

Tags: python, dataframe, regression

I have a database in the following form :

| Date | temp | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | obs1 | r1,1 |
| t1 | obs2 | r1,2 |
| t1 | obs3 | r1,3 |
| t2 | obs1 | r2,1 |
| t2 | obs2 | r2,2 |
| t2 | obs3 | r2,3 |
| t3 | obs1 | r3,1 |
| t3 | obs2 | r3,2 |

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsOXG.png)
....

I want to do a regression linear w.r.t the date on the values "result" for each observation, for example :

For obs1, I consider the values at t1, t2, t3 for the regression and I store the results of the regression in the column "result" at the same index as the value used for the regression at the corresponding time.

Does anyone have a simple idea of how to do this without loop?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, turn columns 'Date' and 'temp' into your data as [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#).

Iterate through the desired indexes to process each subdataframe.

Then, use 'df.loc[ row_indexer, col_indexer ]' to select and asign values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')
```

[image]

```
df.set_index(['temp', 'Date'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
# list of temp unique values
temp_set = df.index.get_level_values("temp").unique()
print(temp_set)
```

[image]

```
#Iterate on each subdataframe
for obs_value in temp_set:
  print(df[df.index.get_loc_level(obs_value,level='temp')[0]]['result'])
```

[image]

```
for obs_value in temp_set:
  result_values = df[df.index.get_loc_level(obs_value,level='temp')[0]]['result']
  # do regression stuff here
  # just an example
  new_result_values = [ f'new value for {obs_value}: {v}' for v in result_values]
  df.loc[df.index.get_loc_level(obs_value, level='temp')[0], 'result'] = new_result_values
```

[image]